# What is C++ `unsigned`?

Tags: c++

What does the type `unsigned` in C++ refer to? Is it exactly the same as `unsigned int`?

[meeting quality standards]

Comment: -1 for lazy question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly the same. See Table 10 in *7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]* for a list of type specifiers and the corresponding specified types. `unsigned` specifies the type "unsigned int", just as `unsigned int` specifies the type "unsigned int".

```
Specifier(s)            Type
```

---

```
_type-name_             the type named
_simple-template-id_    the type as defined in 14.2
char                    “char”
unsigned char           “unsigned char”
signed char             “signed char”
char16_t                “char16_t”
char32_t                “char32_t”
bool                    “bool”
unsigned                “unsigned int”       <<<<<<<<<<<<<
unsigned int            “unsigned int”
signed                  “int”
signed int              “int”
int                     “int”
unsigned short int      “unsigned short int”
unsigned short          “unsigned short int”
unsigned long int       “unsigned long int”
unsigned long           “unsigned long int”
unsigned long long int  “unsigned long long int”
unsigned long long      “unsigned long long int”
signed long int         “long int”
signed long             “long int”
signed long long int    “long long int”
signed long long        “long long int”
long long int           “long long int”
long long               “long long int”
long int                “long int”
long                    “long int”
signed short int        “short int”
signed short            “short int”
short int               “short int”
short                   “short int”
wchar_t                 “wchar_t”
float                   “float”
double                  “double”
long double             “long double”
void                    “void”
auto                    placeholder for a type to be deduced
decltype(_expression_)  the type as defined below
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the same.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types